# Host Angular application on raspberry pi using nginx, socket.io and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, socket.io, raspberry-pi3

I can't find a configuration to make this work. I want to host an angular app (a board game) and a nodejs server (which communicates with the board game) on a raspberry pi via nginx (also already tried apache).
I start to get the feeling it's not a problem with the nginx configuration, but something fundamental I am missing.

#### Working:

- Running the Angular app (via `ng serve`) and the nodejs server (via
  `ts-node ./src/app.ts`) locally
- Running the Angular app (via `ng serve`) local and the nodejs server on the raspberry

#### Not working

- hosting angular app via nginx (putting the content of dist folder (generated by `ng build --prod`) into `var/www/html`) and running nodejs server on raspberry  --> resulting in `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

#### Code

Nodejs Server

```
const Express = require('express')();
const Http = require('http').Server(Express);
const Socketio = require('socket.io')(Http);

Http.listen(3333, () => {
  console.log('Listening at :3333...');
});
```

Angular App Client

```
import { SocketIoConfig, SocketIoModule } from 'ngx-socket-io';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://192.xxx.xxx.xx:3333', options: { transports: ['websocket'] } };

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)],
  exports: [SocketIoModule]
})
export class DataAccessModule {}
```

nginx config

```
    server {
        location ~* \.io {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            add_header X-location contains-io always;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: If I remove my nginx config additions I get the same results. Is there a way to test if the config is used?

Some other weird thing I discovered is, that I only see a blank page and not a single console.log when running the angular app via `ng serve` on the raspberry and go to `localhost:4200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the only thing I needed was a dyndns, instead of localhost or a static ip.

So the client code looks like this:

```
  private socketUrl = 'http://example.ddns.net';
 // also switched to the plain socket.io-client package instead of ngx-socket-io, but I don't think this is necessary
  socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = io(this.socketUrl);
```

and the nginx conf:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.ddns.net;
        root /var/www/app;

        location ^~ /socket.io/ {           
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use ng build instead of ng serve, and direct your Nginx to your dest folder, like this:

```
    location / {
            root   /var/www/angular-deploy; // move your dest into here
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

You can [read this](https://medium.com/@hmurari/serving-angular-app-from-behind-a-nginx-web-server-3579df0b04b1) for more details, hope it will help

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The angular content on the raspberry already is produced by `ng build --prod`

Comment: and does your nginx point the right place?
do you have something in the nginx logs?

Comment: I would say yes, since I can see the application, when typing the IP of the raspberry in the browser. I just can't play the game without the websocket connection.

I see nothing special in the logs.